# Looping Through A Map

Tags: apex, map, loop, iteration

I have a map I want to loop through and remove all duplicate items. Is there a method that can be used like my pseudo code has?

```
public Map<String, User[]> allPeople {
    Map<String, User[]> teams = new Map<String, User[]>();
    ....
    return teams;
}

public plcontroller(){
    for(User[] loopOverAllPeople : allPeople.values()){
    system.debug('*current person: ' + loopOverAllPeople);
    ****pseudo code****
        if(allPeople.get(loopOverAllPeople.Name()) > 1) {
            loopOverAllPeople.Name.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the system debug looks like:

> Administration=(User:{**Name=Joe Smith, Title=CEO, Department=Administration, UserRoleId=1111, Leadership__c=true, Id=123**}, User:{Name=Ally Scott, Title=Receptionist, Department=Administration, ManagerId=987xxxasf, UserRoleId=222, Leadership__c=false, Id=543543}, User:{Name=Billy Bob, Title=Receptionist, Department=Administration, ManagerId=0054354AS, UserRoleId=333, Leadership__c=false, Id=G}, User:{**Name=Joe Smith, Title=CEO, Department=Administration, UserRoleId=1111, Leadership__c=true, Id=123**}, User:{Name=Julia Emez, Title=Receptionist, Department=Administration, Extension=789, Phone=896-899-8745, ManagerId=7894651312, UserRoleId=444, Leadership__c=false, Id=675444566}),
>
> Analytics=(User:{**Name=Tommy Boy, Title=Director of Analytics, Department=Analytics, UserRoleId=77888, Leadership__c=true, Id=6543654**}, User:{Name=Amy Smith, Title=Data Scientist, Department=Analytics, Extension=55, Phone=508-998-8855, ManagerId=45534654654, UserRoleId=22222, Leadership__c=false, Id=545345421}, User:{**Name=Tommy Boy, Title=Director of Analytics, Department=Analytics, UserRoleId=77888, Leadership__c=true, Id=6543654**}),

etc...

Comment: what dont you create Set<> at the first place?

Comment: @SantanuBoral because I need to map a department name to a list of users

Comment: so finally you want to create list of unique users?

Comment: So you have a collection of users and you want to remove any with duplicate names? You could do that when building the first map using `Map<string, Map<string, User>>` where the inner string is the user name.

Comment: @SantanuBoral yes, I want the allPeople User[] list to be editable/ unique.

Comment: @DanielBallinger , what would the string be on the second map? I see this as: `Map<Department, Map<User's Name, List of Users>>`

Comment: I just posted a snippet, the below should help you dedupe your list. I would still recommend keeping it as a set, but if you absolutely need it as a list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this snippet should do it. (I am being more verbose than I need to, for clarity's sake)

```
List<User> usersWithDupes = <your list here>

Set<User> usersUnique = new Set<User>();
usersUnique.addAll(usersWithDupes);

List<User> usersUniqueList = new List<User>();
usersUniqueList.addAll(usersUnique);
```

Comment: I thought the same Sebastian.. but how can u validate uniqueness in set will be based on name ? y dont the uniqueness be on id or some other key ?

Comment: According to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_set_sobject.htm, you don't need the ID.

Comment: lets say List<User> has 3 columns name, company name, role... how can u make sure when u add the list to set, only users with unique names will be in the set.. y not role or nay other field ?

Comment: I can't. But why is it important? If you look at the OP's post, the objects are identical. She does not need to check name only.

Comment: This is not a good use case for `Set<SObject>`.

Comment: It's narrow, but based on what the OP wants, I think it's appropriate. I wouldn't use it unless very specific conditions were met... and I think the OP's code indicates that they do. If you disagree, Adrian, it would be helpful for me if you  justify your comments. I'd love to hear your rationale, it's not unheard of for me to overlook a detail.

Comment: @SebastianKessel it worked, my duplicates are removed but as are the departments. I am going to try and save it back into the map so I can connect the department to the list of users.

Comment: @AdrianLarson why is this not a good use case?

Comment: Because it looks like OP is trying to de-duplicate on one specific field. Honestly I would recommend against them for anyone who doesn't have a solid understanding of how hash tables work under the hood. A simpler structure here would just be a `Map<String, User>`.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. It looks like she used "name" as an example.  Having said that, @Olivia, if your objects are not truly identical, my solution is not the right one and you should look at Daniel's.

Answer (score 4):

So you have a collection of users and you want to remove any with duplicate names? You could do that when building the first map using `Map<string, Map<string, User>>` where the inner string is the user name.

E.g.

```
public Map<String, User[]> allPeople {
    Map<String, Map<string, User>> departmentMap = new Map<String, Map<string, User>>();

    for(User u : [Select Id, Name, Department from User]) {
        Map<string, User> userNamesMap = null;
        if(departmentMap.containsKey(u.Department)) { 
            userNamesMap = departmentMap.get(u.Department);
        } else {
            userNamesMap = new Map<string, User>();
            departmentMap.put(u.Department, userNamesMap);
        } 
        // You might want to decide how to handle Name conflicts here 
        userNamesMap.put(u.Name, u);
    } 

    return departmentMap;
}
```

The outer mapped will be keyed by the Users department. The inner map will be keyed by the user name. As such, you can only have one User per department with each name. It would be possible to have the same User Name in different departments. If that is a problem then you would need to maintain a SET of processed user names that you check before adding the User to the map.

Comment: You could also use [complex keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm) here.